# How do you implement an MPVolumeView?

Tags: ios, iphone, volume, mpvolumeview

I want the user to be able to change the system volume with a slider, and I realized the only way to do this is with an MPVolumeView.

But I can't find any example code for it, and every method I try to implement won't show up.

So what is the easiest and correct, working way of implementing a MPVolumeView?

Comment: Just add it is as a subview of some onscreen view? Should do the job I suppose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place it as a generic `UIView`, then use the inspector to set the class to `MPVolumeView` (ensuring that you also link the MediaPlayer framework). It'll still be shown as a regular slider in IB, but at runtime, it will be an instance of `MPVolumeView` and will have the necessary styles and behavior. Note that this may not work as expected in the iOS Simulator, which doesn't permit volume control.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I only need help placing it in a UIAlertView now.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829234/mpvolumeview-in-a-uialertview

Comment: It works fine by changing a UISlider just make sure to add the  MediaPlayer.framework or else it will just show as a UISlider

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its really annoying that it does not work on the simulator.
 If you want to always hide the button at the right (route button), add also myVolumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;

Answer (score 3):

Use this it will automatically get it

```
mpVolumeViewParentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: mpVolumeViewParentView.bounds];
[mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview: myVolumeView];
[myVolumeView release];
```

Comment: I dont see much help on copying the code from apple´s documentation when someone is asking for an example...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPVolumeView/showsVolumeSlider

Comment: It's very helpful, since you shouldn't post links but solutions. This code will still be here in ten years time (maybe), the link could be invalid next week.

Comment: Wait. But by that logic, what if this link is invalid in ten years? :O. THE INTERNET IS BROKEN! :O. FYI 5 years later and the link is just fine, except that unlike this example, it's been updated and maintained.

Comment: ^ There's no guarantee that a 3rd party link will remain valid.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13 this has changed. Adding a slider in IB with its class set to `MPVolumeView` doesn't work anymore. So the accepted answer no longer works.
The right way, as outlined in the Apple docs, is to use a `UIView` in IB and then in code add the `MPVolumeView` as a subview.
Here's how in Swift:

```
// myVolumeViewParentView is the UIView you put in IB
let myVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: myVolumeViewParentView.bounds)
myVolumeViewParentView.addSubview(myVolumeView)
```

This method works in iOS 12 too.