# MPVolumeView in a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, volume

Is it possibe to put an MPVolumeView in a UIAlertView?

I have tried to *put* it inside of it, but it does not display. It may be the `sizeToFit` or `initWithFrame:` part?
Is there a way of testing if the `MPVolumeView` is actually being created?

Here's the code I initialize both the `UIAlertView` and `MPVolumeView` with:

```
UIAlertView *volumeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Volume" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:volumeAlert.bounds];

[volumeAlert addSubview:volumeView]; 

[volumeAlert sizeToFit];

[volumeAlert show];
[volumeAlert release];
[volumeView release];
```

Comment: Rather than using an `UIAlertView`, I'm just using a simple `UIView` with an transparent image as a "background" for the `MPVolumeView` and some text, and loading that onto the screen, rather than the `UIAlertView`. I am going to keep this question for learning :)

Comment: There seems to be some kind of added support for this here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayerFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007552 ...but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think initing the VolumeView with the VolumeAlert's frame would cause problems. Since VolumeAlert's frame is never being set (before VolumeView's frame is set), you can't depend on it being any size.

Comment: What size would I use for this purpose? I am really bad at creating and placing stuff in code/realtime..

Comment: I would just try something like CGRECTMAKE(0,0,100,20) to see if it show up at all to check to see if that is actually the cause. Though if I remember correctly from other things I have read, UIAlertView is not customizable (without private api's or rolling your own version), so this may all be for not.

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer, because this is the most relevant answer. I do not use this solution afterall, see question.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `MPVolumeSettingsAlertShow()`

> Displays an alert panel for controlling the system volume.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView`, and `UIView` has a convenient `addSubview:` method.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Emil ok.... so is your code working or not?  if it's not, what's happening?  what are you expecting to happen? are any errors being logged?  you can't just say "here's my code, fix it for me"...

Comment: It is not working, the UIAlert pops up, but there is no volume slider there. Could it be the `initWithFrame:` part that's causing it? Do you know a way of testing if it even creates the volumeView?

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out this recent blog post from Jeff LaMarche, should fill your needs - [Custom Alert Views](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html)