# MPVolumeView, avoid displaying "No Volume Available"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, device, volume

I have a project with a `MPVolumeView` in it. It is set up, and it works, the only thing is that when I mute the device, the text `"No Volume Available"` comes up instead of the `MPVolumeView`. I would rather like the slider of the `MPVolumeView` to be disabled when the device is muted.

The volumeView is initialized in the view `volumeBounds`, with that view's bounds.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:volumeBounds.bounds] autorelease];
[volumeBounds addSubview:volumeView]; 
[volumeView sizeToFit];
```

Thanks :)

*If you are interested in helping me with something else, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829234/mpvolumeview-in-a-uialertview)*

Comment: How? The only way to change the volume of the device is with an `MPVolumeView`.

Comment: You can change the volume starting with OS 3.0, See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume

Comment: That won't work with an `AVAudioPlayer`, would it?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer also has a volume property. You can use a UISlider like Kenny suggested and send it's value to the volume property. Thus MPVolumeView is not the only way to control volume.

Comment: How can I achieve it with an MPVolumeView? Thats what I want.

Comment: My question is, how do I avoid displaying the text "No Volume Available" when a device is muted, I would rather like a way to disable the slider of the `MPVolumeView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AudioServices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) to listen for the hardware volume.  When the volume goes to zero, set the alpha of the MPVolumeSlider to zero and place your own disabled UISlider in the same position.  Skin your slider to look like the volume slider.

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener( kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume , ... );
```

`kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChanged` might also be useful.

If you walk the view hierarchy under the MPVolumeView, you should find a UISlider.  If not, or if it is hidden, you know the mute string is showing.

Edit:

[This](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AudioSessionPropertyListener) describes the function prototype for your listener.  To pass the message to an instance of your class, do something similar to:

```
void MyPropertyListener ( void *inClientData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID, UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData );

void MyPropertyListener ( void *inClientData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID, UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData ) {
  if ( inID == kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume ) {
    Float32 volume = *(Float32 *)inData;
    [(MyDelegateClass *)inClientData hardwareVolumeChanged:volume];
  }
}

AudioSessionAddPropertyListener( kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume ,
  MyPropertyListener , aDelegateInstance );
```

Comment: I just don't seem to get it; take a look at this code: `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, @selector(volumeChanged), self);`. That gets a warning that argument 2 is an incompitable pointer type.

Comment: and again, when I do this: `- (void) volumeChanged (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue) { code }` I get the error "Expected { before ( token". What's wrong? All of this AudioSession-stuff is very new to me...

Comment: You have to pass a C function pointer to AddPropertyListener, not a selector, and have the C function call your Objective-C member.  Return type of volumeChanged should be `void` not `-(void)` as it is a C function.

Comment: Do I need to type anything more than volumeChanged where the selector is now? I will try it.

Comment: I no longer get an error at the `void`-part, but I get an error saying that `volumeView` is undeclared. I have declared it allready in the .h-file and connected it properly in IB and everything, but it still won't say that it is declared..

Comment: In .h: ` IBOutlet MPVolumeView *volumeView;` and `@property (retain) MPVolumeView *volumeView;`.
.m: `@synthesize volumeView;`

Comment: I did not understand what your post said, that is why I didn't accept it, if you wondered. How can I use Obective-C objects in these `C`-functions?

Comment: You could as easily ask how to use a C++ object from C.  You just do it.  Objective-C is C.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution for simplicity.

In Objective-C:

```
[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn: [MPVolumeView class], nil].textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In Swift:

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedWithin([MPVolumeView.self]).textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Refer to the following answer for `appearanceWhenContainedWithin` method:
[appearanceWhenContainedIn in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift/28765193#28765193)

It just hides "No Volume Available" text rather than replacing with a disabled UISlider not to worry about the alignment between the MPVolumeView slider and UISlider.

AVPlayer has `volume` property but its document says:

> Use this property to control a player’s audio volume relative to other audio output.

AVAudioSession has read-only `outputVolume` property and its document says:

> The system wide output volume can be set directly only by the user; to provide volume control in your app, use the MPVolumeView class.

For the limitations, the simple solution (or workaround) is just setting the text color to clear.