# appearanceWhenContainedIn in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I'm trying to convert my app to the Swift language.

I have this line of code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
                     setTitleTextAttributes:textDictionary
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

How to convert it to Swift?

In [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance), there is no such method.

Comment: @LukeTheObscure check out my answer below... ugly, but works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26224862/801858

Answer (score 231, accepted):

### Update for iOS 9:

If you're targeting iOS 9+ (as of Xcode 7 b1), there is a new method in the `UIAppearance` protocol which does not use varargs:

```
static func appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(containerTypes: [AnyObject.Type]) -> Self
```

Which can be used like so:

```
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([MyViewController.self]).keyboardAppearance = .Light
```

If you still need to support iOS 8 or earlier, use the following original answer to this question.

### For iOS 8 & 7:

These methods are not available to Swift because Obj-C varargs methods are not compatible with Swift (see http://www.openradar.me/17302764).

I wrote a non-variadic workaround which works in Swift (I repeated the same method for `UIBarItem`, which doesn't descend from `UIView`):

```
// UIAppearance+Swift.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface UIView (UIViewAppearance_Swift)
// appearanceWhenContainedIn: is not available in Swift. This fixes that.
+ (instancetype)my_appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)containerClass;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

—

```
// UIAppearance+Swift.m
#import "UIAppearance+Swift.h"
@implementation UIView (UIViewAppearance_Swift)
+ (instancetype)my_appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)containerClass {
    return [self appearanceWhenContainedIn:containerClass, nil];
}
@end
```

Just be sure to `#import "UIAppearance+Swift.h"` in your bridging header.

Then, to call from Swift (for example):

```
# Swift 2.x:
UITextField.my_appearanceWhenContainedIn(MyViewController.self).keyboardAppearance = .Light

# Swift 3.x:
UITextField.my_appearanceWhenContained(in: MyViewController.self).keyboardAppearance = .light
```

Comment: UIBarButtonItem is not an UIView and needs to be extended separately

Comment: Note that at least in iOS8, UIAppearance+Swift.h should import UIKit/UIKit.h

Comment: UIBarButtonItem can be supported also if you just make another method targeting UIBarButtonItem instead of UIView. @interface UIBarButtonItem (UIViewAppearance_Swift)

Comment: I've added this solution to my code but according to Xcode my UIBarButtonButtonItem doesn't have a member named: .my_appearanceWhenContainedIn

Comment: Update for swift 3?

Comment: @rptwsthi: I've added an example for Swift 3, it's very slightly different

Comment: The iOS 9 version for Swift 3.2 is         UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Done"

Answer (score 32):

**`ios 10 swift 3`**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Kapat"
```

Comment: Don't know why this is downvote since it 's the way to do it in iOS10 swift 3...
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

## For iOS 8 & 7:

I use a category based on Alex's answer to specify multiple containers. This is a workaround until Apple officially supports `appearanceWhenContainedIn` in Swift.

**UIAppearance+Swift.h**

```
@interface UIView (UIAppearance_Swift)
/// @param containers An array of Class<UIAppearanceContainer>
+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedWithin: (NSArray *)containers;
@end
```

**UIAppearance+Swift.m**

```
@implementation UIView (UIAppearance_Swift)

+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedWithin: (NSArray *)containers
{
    NSUInteger count = containers.count;
    NSAssert(count <= 10, @"The count of containers greater than 10 is not supported.");
    
    return [self appearanceWhenContainedIn:
            count > 0 ? containers[0] : nil,
            count > 1 ? containers[1] : nil,
            count > 2 ? containers[2] : nil,
            count > 3 ? containers[3] : nil,
            count > 4 ? containers[4] : nil,
            count > 5 ? containers[5] : nil,
            count > 6 ? containers[6] : nil,
            count > 7 ? containers[7] : nil,
            count > 8 ? containers[8] : nil,
            count > 9 ? containers[9] : nil,
            nil];
}
@end
```

Then add `#import "UIAppearance+Swift.h"` to your bridging header.

**To use from Swift**:

```
TextField.appearanceWhenContainedWithin([MyViewController.self, TableViewController.self]).keyboardAppearance = .Light
```

It was good if I could find a way using [CVarArgType](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/CVarArgType/), but I found no clean solution.

Comment: Nice workaround to the broken-ness of varargs! It's really too bad there's no general solution other than (now) using Apple's iOS 9-only method.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a less ugly, but still ugly, workaround inspired by @tdun.

1. Create a class to hold your Objective-C appearance. For the purposes of this example, let's call it `AppearanceBridger`.
2. Add this class to your bridging header. If you don't have a bridging header, [create one](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78).
3. Create a class method in `AppearanceBridger` named `+(void)setAppearance` and put the Objective-C appearance code in this method. For example:

```
+ (void)setAppearance {
    [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

4. In your Swift code where you set the appearance, call `AppearanceBridger.setAppearance()` and you should be good to go!

Hope this works well for people who see it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an ugly workaround solution I used....

Just make an Objective-C Cocoa Touch Class (UIViewController), named whatever you want.

I named mine `WorkaroundViewController`...

Now in (`WorkaroundViewController.m`):

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

Run the Objective-C appearance code for `.appearanceWhenContainedIn()` (here's my example):

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:16.0f]}];
```

Then [create a bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) for your Swift project and then initialize your Objective-C ViewController in your Swift code, like this (again, just my example):

```
var work : WorkaroundViewController = WorkaroundViewController()
```

Then you're done! Let me know if it works for you... Like I said, it's ugly, but works!

Comment: It is tmp solution, I think we should to find or to wait to some better way :)

Comment: @AlexZd, absolutely, I hope they include it in swift... But for now, if you need it, there ya go!

Answer (score 4):

This can be extended to any class that conforms to the UIAppearance protocol -- not just UIViews. So here's a more generic version:

**UIAppearance+Swift.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NSObject (UIAppearance_Swift)

+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedWithin:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)containerClass;

@end
```

**UIAppearance+Swift.m**

```
#import "UIAppearance+Swift.h"

@implementation NSObject (UIAppearance_Swift)

+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedWithin:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)containerClass {
    if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIAppearance)]) {
        return [(id<UIAppearance>)self appearanceWhenContainedIn:containerClass, nil];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a repo for you guys who wanna use `CocoaPods`:

1. Add this into your `Podfile`:

   ```
   pod 'UIViewAppearanceSwift'
   ```
2. Import in your class:

   ```
   import UIViewAppearanceSwift

   func layout() {
       UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedWithin(MFMailComposeViewController.self).barStyle = .Black
       UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedWithin(UISearchBar.self).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   }
   ```
3. Reference: 
   https://github.com/levantAJ/UIViewAppearanceSwift

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4: iOS 9+**

```
UIProgressView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [LNPopupBar.self]).tintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Swift (at least as of Beta5) isn't able to support it for reasons unknown to me. Perhaps the language feature required is still in progress, as I can only assume they left it out of the interface for a good reason. Like you said, according to the docs it's still available in ObjC. Really disappointing.

Comment: This worked for me in Beta 5 using @spinillos method.

Comment: Right, but `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` is still off the table.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textDictionary, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Edit: appearanceWhenContainedIn was removed in Swift. This answer was for the Beta 5 to change the appearance of the text of all bar buttons.

Comment: Also, no need to use `UIControlState.Normal` you can just use `.Normal` Swift knows the type by inference.

Comment: this will change appearance for all UIBarButtonItems, not for specific one

Comment: @KonstantinKoval Exactly - that's the purpose of the appearance proxies. You can style your entire application without needing to contain boilerplate code/method calls in every view controller.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, in Swift `appearanceWhenContainedIn` has been removed.

Answer (score -7):

You should be able to just translate the `Objective-C` syntax into `Swift` syntax.

In swift the methods should be declared like this:

```
func appearanceWhenContainedIn(containerClass : <UIAppearanceContainer>)
func setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: NSDictionary!, forState state: UIControlState)
```

So you can try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedIn(UINavigationBar).setTitleTextAttributes(textDictionary, forState: UIControlStateNormal)
```

I still have to figure out if this is the clean way to call a class method in `Swift` though.

Hope this helps,

Comment: There is no this method appearanceWhenContainedIn in swift it isn't compile. Error:'UIBarButtonItem.Type' does not have a member named 'appearanceWhenContainedIn'

Comment: Hi @AlexZd, your comment is based on the actual XCode 6 Beta but if you look at the `UIAppearance` protocol documentation (to which `UIBarButtonItem` conforms), the `appearanceWhenContainedIn(_:) method exists (it's just not implemented in Swift yet): https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance

Comment: @Zedenem I know, it's really dumb and you don't want to believe us - but this method literally cannot be called from Swift, check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html - the method is hidden from Swift

Comment: Hi @powerj1984, it's not that I don't want to believe you. I was just hoping at the time I wrote my answer that this was just due to Swift's beta status. The fact that the method hasn't been deprecated but is just hidden from Swift is really strange, and having no explanation from Apple makes it even worst... But you're right, even if I don't understand why, my answer is wrong. Maybe is there a feature in Swift I am not thinking about that would allow us to do just that...

Comment: Haha, sorry - I really mean I don't want to believe me. It's just such a silly thing for Apple to screw up. It's weird as heck!

Comment: I like your optimism thinking the issue might've been fixed before Swift was full on released though :)