# how do I reduce the opacity of the placeholder (not the entire TextField) of TextField in xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a sample login page. In that, I have one textField. I want to change the alpha value(or opacity) of the textfield's placeholder text only. I searched on google but did not get an answer. Please Help!

Comment: You can give it a color & alpha using attributed string. Refer this [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26076202/5620628)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Placeholder Text Color with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076054/changing-placeholder-text-color-with-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the placeholder as an attributed string and set the color as you want it:

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
```