# SwiftUI. How to change the placeholder color of the TextField?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to change the placeholder color of the TextField, but I can't find a method for it.

I tried to set `foregroundColor` and `accentColor`, but it doesn't change the placeholder color.

Here is the code:

```
TextField("Placeholder", $text)
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    .accentColor(Color.green)
```

Maybe there is no API for this yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076054/changing-placeholder-text-color-with-swift You need to assign the `attributedString` to it.

Comment: NSAttributedString does not confirm to StringProtocol.

Comment: You set it on `attributedPlaceholder`?

Comment: There is no `attributedPlaceholder` property in the `TextField`. This is not UITextField.

Comment: Sorry, does this work? https://github.com/SimpleBoilerplates/SwiftUI-Cheat-Sheet#text

Comment: Doesn't work either. But in a previous version of the API, this would work.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

There is no api for it (yet). **BUT YOU CAN**:

Use a custom `placeholder` modifier to show **any view** as the holder of **any other view**! e.g:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .placeholder(when: text.isEmpty) {
        Text("Placeholder recreated").foregroundColor(.gray)
}
```

[image: Demo1]

It's a simple `ZStack` that you can in a `View` extension like:

```
extension View {
    func placeholder<Content: View>(
        when shouldShow: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Content) -> some View {

        ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
            placeholder().opacity(shouldShow ? 1 : 0)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can apply **any** kind of style to the placeholder like this gradient placeholder with image:

[image: Demo2]

✅ If you are interested, Here is **[how to apply resizable gradient on any view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63933797/5623035)**

---

## The Art of the simplicity

Most of the time you need to pass just a string and a gray placeholder like:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .placeholder("Placeholder", when: text.isEmpty)
```

you can write a simple wrapper around the above extension for it:

```
extension View {
    func placeholder(
        _ text: String,
        when shouldShow: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading) -> some View {
            
        placeholder(when: shouldShow, alignment: alignment) { Text(text).foregroundColor(.gray) }
    }
}
```

### Just like that

Comment: This doesnt seem to work on iOS14. TextField is blank, i,e, no placeholder

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day! the default color was unreadable for me without you trick

Comment: Cool idea, I simplified it to this for myself so it wasn't bloated: `func placeholder(when shouldShow: Bool, placeholder: String)`

Comment: @Big_Chair I have added another extension for that, a simple helper that takes a String and sets the Text inside.

Comment: @daihovey that's seems because of ZStack leading alignment issue on iOS 14
Did you find the solution?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini hi, out of interest - maybe you know how to workaround iOS 14 issue when placeholder is not visible? Seems that's related to ZStack leading alignment issue on iOS 14, but not sure.

Comment: set alignment to .topLeading for multiline text fields with reserved space.

Comment: Error: `Value of type 'TextField<Text>' has no member 'placeholder'`

Comment: hen hao, xue dao le！

Answer (score 67):

**For iOS 16.0 and above**

```swift
TextField("", text: $viewModel.userName, prompt: Text("Phone, email or username").foregroundColor(.gray))
```

Comment: We could use that in IOS 15 as well.

Comment: Thank you. i've use it for watchOS 17.

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas Weird, I just tried on my iOS 15 simulator and it's not working

Comment: Is it possible to customize the prompt from a TextFieldStyle?

Comment: it is not possible to customize the prompt form a TextFieldStyle

Answer (score 44):

Eventually a ViewModifier that embeds the content in a ZStack is more elegant and less code:

```
public struct PlaceholderStyle: ViewModifier {
    var showPlaceHolder: Bool
    var placeholder: String

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if showPlaceHolder {
                Text(placeholder)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            }
            content
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(5.0)            
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TextField("", text: $data)
.modifier(PlaceholderStyle(showPlaceHolder: data.isEmpty,
                           placeholder: "My Placeholder"))
```

Comment: This should likely be the new accepted answer until SwiftUI has a native way of changing placeholder colour

Comment: Shouldn't foregroundColor modify Text(placeholder) rather than content?

Comment: I guess not. The foreground color changes what the user type.

Answer (score 23):

It's a bit modification for the [@jfk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041398/5519329), we can create an extension for `view` to simplify the modifier code inside the main view and also it can be used for `Text` and `Image`.

```
struct PlaceHolder<T: View>: ViewModifier {
    var placeHolder: T
    var show: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if show { placeHolder }
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func placeHolder<T:View>(_ holder: T, show: Bool) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PlaceHolder(placeHolder:holder, show: show))
    }
}
```

**Usage in TextField:**

Add this line of code `.placeHolder(Text("Your placeholder"), show: text.isEmpty)` as a `viewModifier` to `TextField`.

```
TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { (changing) in
    print("Changing: \(changing)")
}, onCommit: {
    print("Committed!")
})
    .placeHolder(Text("Your placeholder"), show: text.isEmpty)
```

**Usage in Image:**

Further more, as [@EmilioPelaez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725628/emiliopelaez) suggested, I modified the code to support placeholder for any view for ex. `Image` like below.

```
Image("your_image")
    .placeHolder(Image("placeholder_image"), show: true)
```

Comment: This is a great answer but I think it could be improved some more. Allowing any kind of content instead of requiring `Text` and replacing the `text: String` parameter with `show: Bool` would make it more flexible and it could be used with different kinds of views.

Comment: Ahh.. @EmilioPelaez, that's really good idea to make the place holder available for any view whether it is **Text** or **Image**, I've updated my answer. I stick to the question but your suggestion is simply out of box. Thank you!!

Answer (score 19):

**On iOS 15**, you can use `prompt`

```
public init(text: Binding<String>, prompt: Text? = nil, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

Which works as a placeholder view

Answer (score 18):

### Super easy solution

We can substitute TextField's placeholder with another Text's string.

So, we can control a color of a fake "placeholder".

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty {
                Text("Type Here")
                    .foregroundColor(.red.opacity(0.4))
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
            }
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .font(.system(size: 50))
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers! No need to NSAttributedString

Comment: Great answer, so simple.

Answer (score 6):

```
TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Hello").foregroundColor(.white))
```

change text color in prompt

Comment: this does not seem to work on macOS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the original TextField and you don't mind adding Introspect to your project (https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), you can do it by accessing the UIKit `attributedPlaceholder`:

```
TextField("Email", text: $email)
.introspectTextField { uiTextField in
    uiTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text", 
    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Library is very poor - there's like 80% chance it will work if all you have is a View and TextField. Once you add styling, or move TextField inside VStack and add styling to VStack - it breaks instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Placeholder text color of a TextField:

https://medium.com/app-makers/how-to-use-textfield-in-swiftui-2fc0ca00f75b

```
struct SuperTextField: View {

var placeholder: Text
@Binding var text: String
var editingChanged: (Bool)->() = { _ in }
var commit: ()->() = { }

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        if text.isEmpty { placeholder }
        TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
    }
}   }
```

and usage

```
@State var text: String = "TextField Text"

var body: some View {
    SuperTextField(
        placeholder: Text("Placeholder Text").foregroundColor(.red),
        text: $text
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Along the lines of Mojtaba Hosseini's answer, you can apply a very general/simple solution by using .background to hold any view as your hint/placeholder:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .background(
        ZStack{
            Color.white // <---- whatever your current background is
            if (text == "") {
                AnyView() // <---- any thing you want
            }
        }
    )
```

By using .background instead of ZStack to hold AnyView(), we ensure that AnyView() (Or a GeometryReader if you choose to use one to hold it) will exactly match the size of the TextField, allowing control over AnyView's presentation relative to the TextField regardless of what dynamic/runtime size the TextField has given itself based on dynamic padding(), system font, and other unknown internals.