# Textfield placeholder doesn't shows up well, SwitUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to add login form to white color view but textfield placeholder can't see well, however on preview it shows up.

I tried to change placeholder color [SwiftUI. How to change the placeholder color of the TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688242/swiftui-how-to-change-the-placeholder-color-of-the-textfield/62950092) but it still doesn't shows up well. Could you give me some tip how can I solve this problem?

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.white))
                .frame(height:300)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(16)
                 LoginForm()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginForm: View {
@State var username: String = ""
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.center) {
        UsernameTextField(userNumber: $username)
            .padding(50)
        LoginButton()
    }.padding()
}
```

}

```
struct UsernameTextField: View {
@Binding var userNumber: String
var body: some View {
    TextField("Phone number", text: $userNumber)
        .padding(50)
        .onChange(of: userNumber, perform: { value in
            userNumber = formatNumberTextField(pattern: "+X(XXX) XXX XX XX", phoneNumber: userNumber)
        })
        .frame(height: 48)
        //.textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .accentColor(.black)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
        .underlineTextField()
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the issue? it seems like you have an issue with the color

Comment: I want to show textfield placeholder as on preview, but it can't see well on simulator

Comment: Do you think it's because of color? I tried to use extension as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688242/swiftui-how-to-change-the-placeholder-color-of-the-textfield/62950092 but placeholder is still not showing well :(

Comment: In general textfield placeholder should look like this https://imgur.com/a/QRpIxGH I can't understand why placeholder text can't see well as on this screenshot

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini

Could you please give some tip what may be wrong?

Comment: Isolate your code down to a single field (instead of a full view with buttons and cards and etc.) then play with parameters to find the one that suits you