# How do I set Section attributes in UITableView?

Tags: swift, uikit

**Background**

I would like to set Section attributes in an UITabelLabelCell.

**Original Post with outdated Obj-C Code/approach Below**

This is code to set the font for section headers within a UITable.  I'm trying to adopt this code for iOS7+.

**Obj-C Code**

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:8]];
```

I think it should look something like this (not certain):

```
UILabel.appearanceForTraitCollection( trait: UITraitCollection )
```

but I'm having trouble transcribing the `UITraitCollection`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [appearanceWhenContainedIn in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: Best Current Solution for iOS7+**

Implement a tableView method in your UITableViewDelegate:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView,
     forSection section: Int) {

        // Background color
        view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        // Text Color/Font
        let header = view as UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        header.textLabel.font = my_font // put the font you want here...
    }
```

**ORIGINAL POST BELOW (outdated hacky solution)**

**Investigation**

Searching around scant Apple docs on the subject and SO Q&A, I could not figure out how to use `UITraitCollection`.

However, I seem to have found a possible hack in [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224862/975129).

*I have tested it with an implementation below and it seems to work.*

We need to take three steps to create an Objective-C class method to do the job.  Using bridging headers, we can seamlessly call the method from Swift.

**Add to Bridging Header**

```
#import "BridgeAppearance.h"
```

**Create BridgeAppearance.h**

```
@interface BridgeAppearance : NSObject { }

+ (void)setFontForUITableHeaderFooters: (UIFont*)font;

@end
```

**Create BridgeAppearance.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BridgeAppearance.h"

@implementation BridgeAppearance

+ (void)setFontForUITableHeaderFooters: (UIFont*)font
{
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil]
     setFont: font];
}

@end
```