# iOS 8: UIButton appearance font

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, uiappearance

Trying to set UIButton's font for all buttons using appearance in iOS 8. After Googling, it appears that Apple has changed the way you do this from OS to OS. In iOS 7, this should have worked:

```
    UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont.inviteButtonTitleFont()
```

But it doesn't seem to work anymore. Anyone know how you do it now?

Comment: Are you using playground or putting your UI elements in an app view's tree?

Comment: I'm running the code from my app, not playground.

Comment: Look, this proxy will work properly only if UILabel implements the proxy to change font globally too.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3:**

```
let fontRegular = UIFont(name: "MyCustomRegularFont", size: 17.0)
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self]).font = fontRegular
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

The proxy for font was removed from UILabel.appearance(), so that's the reason why this not works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appearance when contained in method on `UILabel`

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIButton.self]).font = UIFont.inviteButtonTitleFont()
```

This should work in iOS9, see this answer [appearanceWhenContainedIn in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift) for iOS8 and 7 workarounds.

(Disclaimer, I have not compiled the code snippet so beware of typos).

Comment: this doesn't work for me although it seems like it should

Comment: Type 'UILabel' has no member 'appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses'.