# Change status bar colours in MFMailComposeViewController through UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to change the colour of the navigation bar buttons, navigation bar tint colour and text colour, however I don't seem to be getting anywhere. The `MFMailComposeViewController` is being activated via a `UIActivityViewController` and I have tried a few different methods that have worked before (not through a `UIActivityViewController` though).

This is my current code:

```
    UINavigationBar.my_appearanceWhenContainedIn(MFMailComposeViewController).barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

This was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift). I have also tried this:

```
    activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x0096FF)
    activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

I'm also looking to change the status bar colour.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the navigation bar issues for the buttons and title, but still looking for a solution to the status bar. Doing this doesn't work:

```
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: { () in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass the `MFMailViewController` and override its `viewWillAppear` method

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.opaque = false
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Since you only want the status bar to be `lightcontent`when the MFMailComposeViewController is active, you shouldn't put the

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

into your app delegates didFinishLoading. This would set it lightContent for your whole application.

Comment: can you mark this as correct answer if it solved your problem please?

Answer (score 1):

for iOS8 you  use barTintColor  to change the color of status

```
    NSString *invitationText = @"test";
   [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [mc setSubject:@"Test "];
   [mc setMessageBody:invitationText isHTML:YES];
   [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app delegate file and add these lines to your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :)  It will update the status bar color for all view controllers.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

Additionally in your info.plist file add a new key called "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set the value to "NO"

**UPDATE**

To set diffrent styles between views try this:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Then you can return light or dark depending on what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: I have this, but I need the status bar style to be different between view controllers.

Answer (score -2):

`MFMailComposeViewController` sets its own Status-Bar style, which you don't have access to.  You can probably dig into some private APIs to do this, but then your app definitely will be rejected by Apple.

As a side note though, you shouldn't be changing anything about Apple provided UIViewController(s).  They look that way because they're styled after the original app.  It's meant to give users a sense of location and direction in an app. Apple may reject your app, too, because you've changed their stuff.

Comment: While that may be the case, I've had many other apps approved that do exactly the same thing so I'm not too worried about it being rejected.