# Set UINavigationBar appearance whenContainedInInstancesOf to my viewcontroller not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, appearance, bartintcolor

I want to set white barTintColor in some viewcontroller
I have set `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor` 
for all default color but when I use appearance whenContainedInInstancesOf
 It's not change my viewcontroller

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyViewController.self]).barTintColor = .white
```

---

Any idea?. I tried this in my viewcontroller

```
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.barTintColor = .white
```

but I have to set color back to default when screen will disappear. I don't want to do like that. How can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [appearanceWhenContainedIn in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift)

Comment: @zombie I tried this `UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyViewController.self]).barTintColor = .white` but it still not work!

Comment: But it says that it's only for iOS 10 so which version are you testing on

Comment: @zombie my device is 10.1.1.

Answer (score 8):

`UINavigationBar` is contained in a `UINavigationController` not `UIViewController`

with that said you need to create a custom `UINavigationController`

an empty class will do the job

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {}
```

then we can use it

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [NavigationController.self]).barTintColor = .white
```

Example can be found [here](https://github.com/omiz/Appearance)

Comment: I think this will change others screen too. which screens are next to first screen (screen that's need white navigationbar).

Comment: if you mean that this will change the color for `UINavigationController` too then no. it will take effect only for `NavigationController`

Comment: @Oniikal3 by the way did you think or try?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. It's show as I think. It's change all screen that's in flow.
Now I have to set it in each viewcontroller. I don't want to struck on it. Thanks for your solutions :)

Comment: @Oniikal3 that's strange anyway I added an example to take a look at. Please let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: This should be the correct answer, you saved my day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

@zombie has the correct answer. I just came across this issue a moment ago with UISearchBar. Here's the Swift 3 version of the answer. Using `.red` as the sample `UIColor` for this example.

```
 let textField = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
 textField.tintColor = .red

 let searchBar = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
 searchBar.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: .red], for: .normal)
 searchBar.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: .red], for: .disabled)
```

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
    // For the cursor color
    let textField = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    textField.tintColor = .lightBlue

    // For the cancel button on search bar
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightText], for: .disabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIImagePickerController.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .normal)
```

This worked for me!